# Multisite Subdomain Redirect Mask

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess

I've seen many questions and answers regarding this subject, yet I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is my setup.

I have my main domain:

**www.example.com**

On that domain, I've installed WP multisite as a subdomain. The root of the network sits at:

**sites.example.com**

I have multiple wordpress sites setup under that subdomain, all under the format of:

**sites.example.com/Some-WP-Site/**

Now, if I register some new domains for the purpose of pointing them to these individual wordpress sites, how would I edit my .htaccess files to achieve something like the following:

User navigates to:

**www.New-Domain.com**

and gets redirected to:

**sites.example.com/Some-WP-Site/**

all while still seeing **www.New-Domain.com** in the address bar.

I've managed to setup a mask where **www.New-Domain.com** is *always* displayed in the address bar, but I would like to have the structure of the site follow the domain, as the user navigates through the site.

For example,

**sites.example.com/Some-WP-Site/wp-content/image.jpg**

would become

**www.New-Domain.com/wp-content/image.jpg**

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish that with `.htaccess` redirects.  In my experience, when a browser hits a `.htaccess` redirection, it simply goes to the new URL.  What you're trying to do sounds like something you'd need to do in PHP -- possibly using WordPress's [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). (Or maybe a domain mapping plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).)